# Specify folder path to XML file in Android

Tags: android, fileinputstream

I put my employeedetailxml into a folder named "res\raw". When I attempt to open it by specifying the file and folder name, I get the error "file not found".

How can I specify the path to my file?

I would much prefer to be able to pass '**R.raw.employeedetailxml**' to `FileInputStream` to specify that it open that file. Is that possible? (I tried it, and got an error.)

Can `FileInputStream` take a Resource ID as parameter?

```
try{
   SAXParserFactory spf=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
   SAXParser sp=spf.newSAXParser();
   XMLReader xr=sp.getXMLReader();

   EmployeeDetailHandler empDetailHandler=new EmployeeDetailHandler();
   xr.setContentHandler(empDetailHandler);

   xr.parse(new InputSource(new FileInputStream("\\res\\raw\\employeedetailxml.xml")));
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can use something similar to passing `R.raw.employeedetailxml`. You just need to fetch the resource XML file using that resource name, like so:

```
InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file_name);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
InputStream inputStream =
    getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.employeedetailxml);
```

Answer (score 4):

`this.getResources().openRawResource()` returns an `InputStream` that will probably help you to parse the xml.

Answer (score 1):

**If placing your xml file under assets doesn't hurt,** you can try out this one:

```
AssetManager manager = getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = manager.open("pathUnderAssets/filename.xml");
```

Please note that getAssets() call is made on context. So, you must call it with context in classes which is not an Activity.